# If $f(x-4) = x^3 + 2x^2 + 7x + 1$, determine $f(x)$.

Tags: functions

I was faced with a pretty tricky math problem from my school. Here is the question.

If $f(x-4) = x^3 + 2x^2 + 7x + 1$, determine $f(x)$.

My first instinct is to graph the initial equation and shift it $4$ points to the right, I saw the $(x-4)$. Would this be the correct way to start?

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I understand what you guys are saying about replacing the f(x). Just to make sure, you want me to replace f(x) with f(y) and then plug in y + 4 for every single x value in the original equation? (P.S. I am the original poster, I just registered)

Comment: **Hint**  Put $y = x - 4$, that is  $x = y + 4$.  Finally just replace $x$ by $y$ and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Note, however, that $f(x-4)$ is the same thing as $f(x)$ but shifted to the right by 4 units. Thus, to get $f(x)$ you have to shift back to the *left*. This is a good way to go if you want to visualize geometrically the relationship between $f(x)$ and $f(x-4)$. If you are just looking for an equation, however, there is an easier way.

Come up with some other variable name, such as $y$, and then let $y=x-4$. Solving for $x$ you get $x=y+4$. Now take your equation for $f(x-4)$ and rewrite it in terms of your new variable $y$.

You should have an equation now with $f(y)$ on the left hand side. Since it doesn't matter what name you call your variables by, you can now just replace all occurrences of $y$ with $x$ and you will have your expression for $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$x = (x+4) - 4$

so $f(x) = f((x + 4) -4) = (x+4)^3 + 2(x+4)^2 + 7(x+4) +1$.